# 3 or 4 days transport card in Paris including airport?

Tags: trains, public-transport, paris

What is the most economical transport card for unlimited use for 3 or 4 days (starting from Saturday), including the train/bus from Charles de Gaulle Airport airport to the city.

Answer (score 5):

Your options are:

- Point-to-point tickets. For transportation inside the Paris city limits (where most tourist attractions are, but not the airports, Versailles or Disneyland), buy 10 [tickets t+](https://www.ratp.fr/en/titres-et-tarifs/t-tickets) for €14.90. From Roissy CDG [airport](https://www.ratp.fr/en/titres-et-tarifs/airport-tickets), a train ticket (cheapest reasonable option) costs €10.30. To visit Versailles, 2 tickets (there and back) cost [€7.30](https://www.ratp.fr/en/titres-et-tarifs/ile-de-france-idf-point-point-tickets). [Children under 10](https://www.ratp.fr/en/titres-et-tarifs/reduced-fares-children) pay half price, children under 4 travel free.
- Day pass ([Mobilis](https://www.ratp.fr/en/titres-et-tarifs/mobilis)). The cost is €7.50 inside Paris, €12.40 valid to Versailles, €17.80 valid to Roissy CDG airport. It's rarely worth it.

  - There's also a much cheaper [youth day pass](https://www.ratp.fr/en/titres-et-tarifs/weekend-day-passes-youth) if you're under 26, valid only on Saturdays, Sundays and [public holidays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_France). It doesn't cover the main airport links (but allows the local buses that go through the airport, if you're ok with a slow trip on buses which don't have much space for luggage).
- [Weekly pass](https://www.ratp.fr/en/titres-et-tarifs/navigo-monthly-and-weekly-travel-passes) for €27.90 (valid for the whole region, including a one-time €5 fee to get the pass itself). These are priced for commuters so they're a lot cheaper, but a week runs from Monday to Sunday, and you can only buy one for the current week until Thursday night.
- [Paris Visite](https://www.ratp.fr/en/titres-et-tarifs/paris-visite-travel-pass). It's usually more expensive than other options (53.75€ for 3 days, 65.80€).

So in your case, point-to-point tickets are likely the cheapest option.